# AI - video - human skeleton detection and movement

Tags: python, video, artificial-intelligence

I have been thinking about a project for a while now but I don't really know where to start.

**I would like to trace the human skeleton in slowmo videos and compare different athelets and their movement during basketball shots, baseball swins, golf swings, ecc.
I want to extract the skeleton movement, angles, tilts, speed, acceleration and all kinds of data but I really don't know where to start.**

I'm a software developer and have been working as a professional for six years now.

I mostly use python but I usually develop big crawlers, utility softwares, backend applications on linux servers ecc.
I had some experience with tensorflow for object detection in images a few years ago, but it was a very basic train of a inception v3 pre-trained.

I know it's going to be a hard task and I would like to have some recommendations for tools needed for this task. I would prefer to use tools that work with python since it's very familiar to me.

Thank you in advance.

---

Answer (score 1):

I do not really understand your specific requirement.

You can find a lot of websites/products that can extract to some degree the motion from one single video. https://www.google.com/search?q=motio+tracking+from+video

If you want to put your test subjects in a controlled environment with a motion capture suit, or at least some markers you could use Blender. It has its own motion capture add-ons.

They of course can not see the skeleton. They will only give you reference points with some offset.

For the skeleton part, you need to now add the motion to a 3D skeleton model with constraints for the articulations, probably with some Inverse Kinematics.

Blender is based on Phyton and it is open source, so probably you can play with it.
https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=motion+capture+blender

For the speed and other measurements, you probably need a database and define those changes between the keyframes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! All examples are very interesting.